# Webdriver Sampler unable to load the page on the browser and exit with an error in JMeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Am trying to load my page on the browser using webdriver sampler and perform few action, but it is exiting with below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'L511024', ip: '192.168.0.180'
Build info: version: '4.13.0', revision: 'ba948ece5b*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--start-maximized,, remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}, proxy: Proxy(system)}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
```

Although I have configured the driver properly inside the `chrome driver config` as below,

I tried with both 64bit and 32bit drivers and I am getting same result, with the below config:

1. Driver Config :

   (1) Path to driver : C:\Users\Downloads\WEBDRIVER\32Driver\chromedriver.exe | C:\Users\Downloads\WEBDRIVER\32Driver\chromedriver.exe
   Tried with Path to driver : C:\Users\Downloads\WEBDRIVER\32Driver\chromedriver.exe | C:\Users\Downloads\WEBDRIVER\32Driver\chromedriver.exe (to remove all the posibility of failure)

   (2)Development (disabled| unchecked)

   (3)Accept Insecure Certs (disabled| unchecked)

   (4)Headless (disabled| unchecked)

   (5)Maximize the browser (disabled| unchecked) [tried with optioned checked also]

   (6)Create a new browser at a start of each iteration (disabled| unchecked)
2. Options Config : --start-maximized, remote-allow-origins=*
3. Proxy Config : User System proxy setting (selected)
4. Capabilities Management: Null

Code : `Script Language Groovy`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

def wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,15000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("Launch Page");
WDS.browser.get('<app_url>');

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

Tool Version:

1. JMeter : 5.6.3 [Latest]
2. Java Version : java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
3. Chrome driver : 120 as the chrome version of the system is 120.0 (driver catalog : https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)
4. Web Driver Version : 4.13.0

My Current Chrome Version:
[image]

Driver is launching with data and then with with error;
[image]

Work around tried
I tried also with changing the `system.property` file by adding the following line

```
webdriver.chrome.bin=<32bit driver location>
```

And also tried with

```
webdriver.chrome.bin=<64bit driver location>
```

Same error is shown in the log file as well, anything I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have 64-bit Chrome, Java and operating system, you need to use 64-bit ChromeDriver
2. Chrome and ChromeDriver versions must match
3. Maybe there is a problem with the system under test which causes browser crash, try simple neutral URL like `http://example.com` or `http://blazedemo.com`
4. Your code won't compile because there is no constructor for [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) which takes Integer as the second argument in Selenium 4.13

   you will need to change this line:

   ```
    def wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,15000);
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(15000))
   ```

   if your code is compiled it means that your Selenium [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) installation is wrong and you created yourself a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell).

If you want us to validate your JMeter installation you need to provide [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) with [JMeter log level verbosity set to debug](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging).

Comment: Still I am observing the same, may be I create myself a Jar Hell